# Converting VHD image to RAW format

Tags: linux, vhd

I need to convert a VHD file (Hyper-V VM) to the Linux raw format. Is there a tool which can do this which is graphical?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why must it be graphical?

```
qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw something.vhd something.raw
```

*(Edit: Fixed `-f vhd` to `-f vpc`.)*

Comment: It doesn't work in QEMU on MacOS; the right way is to use `vpc` instead of `vhd`

Comment: on the linux there is no vhd format, use vhd instead

Answer (score 17):

The correct format is:

```
qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw lamp-3-x86.vhd lamp.raw
```

From the manpages of `qemu-img`:

> `qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw lamp-3-x86.vhd lamp.raw`
>   `vpc` – VirtualPC compatible image format (VHD).

Comment: Yup, that's what the man page says.